# Trying to instantiate a sub UIView within my UIViewController: Why can't I put my '.addSubview' method in a separate function?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm learning how to build a ViewController programmatically, but my one question is: Why can't I state `view.addSubview(inputInfoContainerView)` under `func setupInputInforContainerView()` at the end of the declaration of this function? Why do I have to have `view.addSubview(inputInfoContainerView)` under `func viewDidLoad()`?

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    //CONTAINER VIEW
    let inputInfoContainerView: UIView = {
    let containerView = UIView()
    containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    containerView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    return containerView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 60, g: 90, b: 150)
    //I understand where this is where it should go but need clarification on why

    setupInputInfoContainerView()
}

func setupInputInfoContainerView() {

    //CONSTRAINTS: x, y, width, height
    inputInfoContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    inputInfoContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 40) .isActive = true
    inputInfoContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
    inputInfoContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true

    view.addSubview(inputInfoContainerView)

}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return.lightContent
}

}

extension UIColor {

convenience init(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) {
    self.init(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: 1)
}

}
    }
```

Comment: 1. Making the UI programmatically should be using the callback `loadView()` not in `viewDidLoad`, 2. I think your problem is that you didn't set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`, this made conflict in your constraints and made this view didn't appear

Comment: @user9335240 I already have it set to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your subview to the superview before adding any constraints, like this:

```
func setupInputInfoContainerView() {

    view.addSubview(inputInfoContainerView)

    //CONSTRAINTS: x, y, width, height
    inputInfoContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    inputInfoContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 40) .isActive = true
    inputInfoContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
    inputInfoContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true

}
```

Comment: I already stated in the question that I knew how to resolve the issue. Rather than a solution, I was asking for an explanation.

Comment: Basically, you can not create constraints between views that are not in the same hierarchy. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for your help.